# pytz - convert a datetime in the future to UTC

Tags: pandas, pytz

I have a file that contains *forecasted* events for the next two weeks. There is a datetime column which has the date and each 30 minute interval, and a time zone column.

I am using pytz to convert the different time zones (around 30+ unique ones) to UTC before loading them into a database. However, for the forecast file I am receiving an error:

NonExistentTimeError: 2016-10-16 00:00:00

Is there a way to go about this?

```
date    interval    time_zone
10/26/2016  22:30   US/Central
10/26/2016  22:30   US/Eastern
10/26/2016  23:00   America/Bogota
10/26/2016  23:00   Asia/Calcutta
```

Current code:

```
for tz in df['time_zone'].unique():
    df.loc[df['time_zone'] == tz, 'datetime_utc'] = df.loc[df['time_zone'] == tz, 'datetime'].dt.tz_localize(tz).dt.tz_convert('UTC')
df['datetime_utc'] = df['datetime_utc'].dt.tz_localize(None)
```

Comment: For what time zone is it failing?

Comment: Ah, this was being done as I read in the data (method chaining) so I figured it was for any value. I checked for that date and googled and I narrowed it down to Brazil. tz = 'Brazil/East'
df3.loc[df3['time_zone'] == tz, 'datetime_utc'] = df3.loc[df3['time_zone'] == tz, 'datetime'].dt.tz_localize(tz).dt.tz_convert('UTC')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [changes in daylight saving happening on the 16th October](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil/brasilia), 2016-10-16 00:00:00 really is a local time that does not exist for Brazil (It should instead read 2016-10-16 01:00:00)